# Monorepo shared libs for ReactJs, Material-ui, etc

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, shared-libraries, monorepo

I'm exploring monorepos and I would like to have the following setup:

```
/apps = applications
/components = many individual components
/shared = hostsource libs for reactjs, material-ui, etc
```

Reasoning: I'd like to import reactjs and material-ui from one place for all components and apps. In the future when it's time to upgrade I only touch one project to upgrade core libs.

I think monorepos are made to solve for this right?  upgrading multi-repos has proven difficult. Suggestions.  Perhaps a better approach..

Thank in advance,

not sure yet how to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your components inside shared packages and apps separate and still update and add have same dependencies across your mnorepo.

1. You can use a `package.json` linter like [manypkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@manypkg/cli). So when you run `manypkg` it will go through all your apps and packages and match it same dependency version. Here is an example from `Turborepo` monorepo in their official docs. [Handle mismatch package version](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/troubleshooting)
2. Another option you have is to keep your shared packages like `mui` in the root of `monorepo` instead of individual app or package. Now all your apps and packages will read mui package from `root` (one same place).

I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you so much.  i would like to have one source of truth for important libs like mui and react. the second option sounds better.  i'm trying to achieve this with Rushjs but not much luck.. i'm new to it also